# Add static images to bottom of view page

Tags: 7, views

I have a view called Courses, which outputs an table of college courses. I'd like to add two standalone images to the bottom of the page. Fairly simple really, but I'm not sure how to implement this layout. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view edit form, find 'FOOTER' (under Page Settins), click 'Add' and select 'Global: Text area'

In the content textarea, add your images markup (e.g. `<img src="http://example.com/some_image.png" alt="This is my image!"/>`), change text format to "Full HTML" and save.

Comment: Thank you that worked. For what it's worth, I ended up implementing a panel and adding 'New custom content' to it. Same idea, different approach.